# Can I optimize this at all?

Tags: performance, optimization, uitableview, ios

I'm working on an iOS app and I'm using the following code for one of my tables to return the number of rows in a particular section:

`return [[kSettings arrayForKey:@"views"] count];`

Is there any other way to write that line of code so that it is more memory efficient?

**EDIT:**

`kSettings` = `NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults`.

Is there any way to rewrite my line of code so that whatever memory it occupies is released sooner than it is released now?

Comment: have you measured its performance?

Comment: @Jacob Relkin Based on the usage, it seems to be an instance of `NSUserDefaults`, which makes optimization a valid inquiry, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the first thing that comes to my mind is "Why are you fetching the array from `NSUserDefaults` every single time `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is invoked?"

Store a pointer reference to this array in your `UIViewController` subclass like this:

```
@interface YourViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSArray *views;
}
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *views;

- (void) reload:(BOOL) reloadTable;

//...
@end

@implementation YourViewController

@synthesize views;

- (void) reload:(BOOL) reloadTable {
  [self setViews:[NSUserDefaults arrayForKey:@"views"]];
  if(reloadTable) 
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
} 

- (void) viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  //...
  [self reload:NO];
}


- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *) table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger) section {
   return [[self views] count];
}

//...

@end
```

When you need to fully reload the table's data, just invoke `[self reload:YES]`.

The way that this approach helps you is because it only re-fetches the data from `NSUserDefaults` when you invoke `-reload:`, which cuts down on the amount of times `NSUserDefaults` is accessed.

Answer (score 2):

Does it need to be more performant? Always remember the first two rules of optimization:

1. Don't do it
2. (For experts only) Don't do it yet.

Specifically, if the application is running slowly, it's important to figure out where, exactly, the slowdown is occurring. It never seems to be in the place you think it is, so you have to profile and find out for sure. Investigate Instruments.

Just saying. :-)

Comment: I agree in a general sense, but if the *cost* (in the sense of code complexity and time investment) of optimizing is sufficiently low, and the optimization is actually a valid one, there's no reason **not** to do it. Leaving code unoptimized because it's "good enough" is the reason that everyone needs gigabytes and gigabytes of RAM these days. :P

Comment: Justin, you're missing the point. The reason you don't optimize isn't because we have massive amount of RAM and high speed processors, it's because it's more important to get the functionality working, then use a profiler to find out exactly where you need to optimize, not where you *think* you need to optimize.

Comment: -1: Useless answer. Could be the answer to ANY optimization question. Give the poster a little credit, and assume he has a valid reason for asking.  There ARE real optimization questions, and they're usually hard. If everyone answered every optimization question with this generic answer, nothing would ever run fast.

Comment: Not useless, prudent. Being reminded of the basics is always important, because we all forget them from time to time.

Comment: Failing to answer the question doesn't help anyone.  If he wanted platitudes, he could google "optimization".

Comment: The two rules I mentioned *do* help people, despite your comments. It's neither useless advice, nor is it a platitude. He could google lots of things, but he didn't, he asked here. You're welcome to provide a better answer if you want, and maybe it'll get voted up. Regardless, it's better than the whining you're doing now.